What should be the height of a modal that has a form that discloses progressively?
In the enterprise application that I am designing for, I have a modal that contains an input form. This form has two checkboxes. On selecting each of these text boxes, new fields show up in the form. (A dropdown will appear on selecting the first checkbox, and a file uploader + an input field for the second checkbox).

Here are some questions that I am running into:

Does it make sense to increase the height of the modal based on the content? (Yes, I would add a scrollbar, if the modal is exceeding 80% of the screen height)
Should I choose to make the form a two-step one? But this is where it gets messy: Initially the modal's CTA would say 'Create Item'. But with a multi-step form upon selecting the checkboxes, the CTA should be changed to 'Next' instead of 'Create Item'. Is it a good UX practice to change the CTA altogether?

What would be the best way to solve the problem, considering best UX practices?

Some people will differ depending on their experience on what you are intended to complete on the modal. There is this article about when to use/avoid modals. This link can help you define the best UX for your app.
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/modal-nonmodal-dialog/
However you see in lots of web apps, modals to create tasks rather than just inform the user a feedback. If you follow the approach to have two steps in the modal to create the item you can switch the name of the buttons to inform what's coming. In my experience that's better than modify the height of the pop-up that could not be noticeable to the user and hide the lower part of your form.
The best UX is the one you can make the task easier for the user and avoid friction to complete the task.
Here is an example of what you can do.


